# How do I remove the horizontal space around my list image?

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, whitespace

On [my website](http://glutenfreeradio.co/music), I have had a list format menu at the top of the screen. I was wanting to place a small version of my company logo in the center of this menu, so I just added another list item for it on the [test page](http://glutenfreeradio.co/test):

```
<nav id="main-navigation" data-content-field="navigation-mainNav">
     <ul class="cf">
          <li class="">
               <a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/music/">Music</a></li>
          <li class="">
               <img src="/assets/img/glutenfreeradio.png" style="width:20%;height:20%;" /></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that, as you can see by viewing the links above, some ridiculous extra space has been added on the left and right sides of the list image. I definitely do not want that. I've been scouring the CSS and trying to figure out how to change it either there or directly in the HTML, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image's inline styles are creating that space. Move those to the parent and adjust as needed.

```
<nav id="main-navigation" data-content-field="navigation-mainNav">
     <ul class="cf">
          <li class="">
               <a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/music/">Music</a></li>
          <li class="" style="width:20%;height:20%;">
               <img src="/assets/img/glutenfreeradio.png"/></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/reviews/">Reviews</a></li>
          <li class="">
               <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow. Such a simple fix. I feel pretty dumb. Thanks so much!

Now here is a new but related question:
Now that the logo is where it should be horizontally speaking, the text list items have been pushed down to line up with the bottom of the logo list item. How do I position them to be centered with the logo list item?

Comment: @StephenShutters add `.info-page-layout-poster #main-navigation ul { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }`

Comment: @StephenShutters LOL happy to help

Comment: Oh, man. I'm sorry to bother you yet again, but upon further inspection, it seems adding that `justify-content: center;` bit has actually moved the navigation bar just a bit to the left of center now. Quite ironic. You can see for yourself [here](http://glutenfreeradio.co/music).

Comment: @StephenShutters because the text link elements are different widths (because the words have different # of characters). Try removing `justify-content` (or don't, doesn't matter) and add `.info-page-layout-poster #main-navigation ul li { flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; }`. That will space those elements out evenly so they're the same width, though it will make the menu display differently. If you don't like the look of that, post this as a question and feel free to ping me here about it if you like. It's getting to be a little much for the comments.